# Adding a JMenuItem to a JMenu Causes Menu Bar to Disappear

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

When I try to add a menu item to a menu, the menu bar disappears. The following code:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class WedgeTextFrame  {  

    public static void main(String[] args){

         JFrame f = new JFrame("Menu");
         f.setVisible(true);
         f.setSize(400,400);
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

         JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
         JMenu tools = new JMenu("Tools");
         menubar.add(file);
         menubar.add(tools);

         f.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    }
}
```

results in

[image]

When I add the following lines just after `menubar.add(tools);` that define and add a `JMenuItem` to a `JMenu`:

```java
JMenuItem exit_item = new JMenuItem("Exit");
tools.add(exit_item);
```

The menu bar disappears. I am running Eclipse 2019-06 with JRE 1.8.0

Answer (score 1):

That's where the "All Swing applications must run on their own thread" part comes. Take a look at [initial threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and [the Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Starting your application by calling `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` will solve your problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Menu");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu tools = new JMenu("Tools");
        menubar.add(file);
        menubar.add(tools);

        JMenuItem exit_item = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        tools.add(exit_item);

        f.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    });
}
```

I also advice you to `frame.setVisible(true)` after the whole frame is prepared:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Menu");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //add stuff to frame

    f.setSize(400, 400);
    f.setVisible(true); //Here at the end
});
```

Comment: `f.setVisible(true); //Here at the end
    f.setSize(400, 400);` should instead be `f.pack(); // don't need to guess a size! f.setVisible(true); //Here at the end`. 1) Setting a size should be done before setting a frame visible. 2) The 400 x 400 size is no better than a guess. Calling `pack()` will make the GUI as big as it needs to be in order to show the components it contains.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did not include the whole `pack();` thing, because i thought is a different story. Maybe i was wrong... Anyway, like always, thanks for the additions, +1!

Comment: @SimonPeterkin No problem. Take a look at [what should i do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).